# Turn an array of structs into a binary search tree

Tags: c, arrays, struct, binary-search-tree

So I have an array of structs which i want to turn into a binary search tree.Here is what my code looks like.

```
typedef struct Student{
    char name[25];
    char surname[25];
    char Id[8];
    double grade;
}Student;

struct TNode
{
    struct TNode* data;
    struct TNode* left;
    struct TNode* right;
};

struct TNode* newNode(struct TNode* data);

/* A function that constructs Balanced Binary Search Tree from a sorted array             
*/
struct TNode* sortedArrayToBST(struct Student** students, int start, int end)
{
    /* Base Case */
    if (start > end)
      return NULL;

    /* Get the middle element and make it root */
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    struct TNode *root = newNode(students[mid]);

    /* Recursively construct the left subtree and make it
       left child of root */
    root->left =  sortedArrayToBST(students, start, mid-1);

    /* Recursively construct the right subtree and make it
       right child of root */
    root->right = sortedArrayToBST(students, mid+1, end);

    return root;
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct TNode* newNode(struct TNode * data)
{
    struct TNode* node = (struct TNode*)
                     malloc(sizeof(struct TNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}

/* A utility function to print preorder traversal of BST */
void preOrder(struct TNode* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%s %s %s %.2f ", node->data);
    preOrder(node->left);
    preOrder(node->right);
}
```

And here is how I call the functions in my main.

```
struct TNode *root = sortedArrayToBST(&students, 0, n-1);
```

This doesn't seem to be working for some reason although the array of structs works ok inside of my main function. I always sort my array of structs inside of my main before calling the sortedArraytoBST function. Please help me.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give you *some* warning on `struct TNode *root = newNode(students[mid]);`?

Comment: Yeah but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure whether this answer is *complete* because your code isn't complete, so I can't test it.

Still, there's one "obvious" error: You declare

```
struct TNode* newNode(struct TNode* data);
```

but you call it with

```
struct TNode *root = newNode(students[mid]);
```

where `students[mid]` is a `struct Student *`.

Pointers to different types are **not** compatible in C. I *guess* what you wanted to have is some "*generic*" B-Tree. There's a solution in C: The **generic** pointer is `void *`. You can't dereference it, but you *can* convert it implicitly from and to any other (data) pointer type.

So the least you should do is change your `struct`:

```
struct TNode
{
    void *data;
    struct TNode *left;
    struct TNode *right;
};
```

and your function prototype:

```
struct TNode* newNode(void *data);
```

---

in your `preOrder` function, you try to `printf()` a whole struct -> this isn't possible, `printf()` needs exactly one argument per conversion specifier! So change it e.g. to this (if you know `data` always points to a `struct Student`):

```
void preOrder(struct TNode* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    struct Student *stud = node->data;
    printf("%s %s %s %.2f ", stud->name, stud->surname, stud->id, stud->grade);
    preOrder(node->left);
    preOrder(node->right);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Now this might be a dumb question but I still have a problem with      printf("%s %s %s %.2f ", node->data);    I think i know what's wrong with it but how can I access the array to print it for example ?

Comment: Thanks but now I get a segmentation fault.